# Can realloc fail when shrinking buffer?

Tags: c, realloc

Is it possible that `realloc` fails, when the new size is smaller than the old size of the buffer? In this example the buffer is resized from 100 to 50 bytes.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int, char**)
{
    void* b,* a;

    a = malloc(100);

    if(!a)  return 1;

    b = realloc(a, 50);

    if(!b)
    {
        puts("Is this reachable?");
        free(a);
        return 1;
    }

    free(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nowhere is written that it cannot, hence it can.